# How to disable TRACE method in jetty?

Tags: http, jetty

How can I disable TRACE http method in Jetty? I'm using Jetty version 8.
I want to disable it cause it is a security issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java embedded jetty is accepting HTTP TRACE method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348328/java-embedded-jetty-is-accepting-http-trace-method)

Answer (score 4):

I've investigated that TRACE is disabled by default so there is no issue.

Comment: I don't think this is true for embedded Jetty.

Comment: This is only true for non-embedded Jetty. Embedded deployments of Jetty will need to disable TRACE with a security handler or doing something else. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348328/java-embedded-jetty-is-accepting-http-trace-method