# Java embedded jetty is accepting HTTP TRACE method

Tags: spring, http, jetty, trace, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to disable HTTP TRACE method in embedded Jetty. In Jetty doc's is info that HTTP trace is disabled by default, but for embedded it is still enabled. I was trying to disable trace as a security constraint as is done in jetty.xml.

```
    ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
    servletHandler.setClassLoader(Server.class.getClassLoader());
    servletHandler.setContextPath("/");
    servletHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener());
    servletHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new CXFServlet()), "/*");
    servletHandler.setInitParameter("contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName());
    servletHandler.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", BeansConfig.class.getName());
    servletHandler.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", DispatcherConfig.class.getName());

     /*
     * <security-constraint>
     * <web-resource-collection>
     * <web-resource-name>Disable TRACE</web-resource-name>
     * <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     * <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
     * </web-resource-collection>
     * <auth-constraint/>
     * </security-constraint>
     */
     Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
     constraint.setName("Disable TRACE");

     ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
     mapping.setConstraint(constraint);
     mapping.setMethod("TRACE");
     mapping.setPathSpec("/"); // this did not work same this mapping.setPathSpec("/*");

     ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = (ConstraintSecurityHandler) servletHandler.getSecurityHandler();
     securityHandler.addConstraintMapping(mapping);
```

Example output from soapUI:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: message/http
Content-Length: 143
Server: Jetty(9.0.6.v20130930)

TRACE / HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Host: 192.168.33.115
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `Constraint` object, you need to call `setAuthenticate(true)`, and ensure that you don't call `setRoles(String[])`. This makes it the equivalent of a `<security-constraint>` with an empty `<auth-constraint>`, which forbids access.

The reason it works with the `DefaultServlet` and not the `CXFServlet` is because the `DefaultServlet` specifically denies access to the TRACE method.

Answer (score 9):

Extending the Server class and overriding the handle() method worked best for me.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

public class MyServer extends Server {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpChannel<?> connection) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Request request=connection.getRequest();
        Response response=connection.getResponse();

        if ("TRACE".equals(request.getMethod())){
            request.setHandled(true);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        } else {
            super.handle(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An `HttpConfiguration.Customizer` would probably be more appropriate, easier, and more future proof. (the `Server.handle()` API has changed a few times over the years)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a filter:

```
...
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if ("TRACE".equalsIgnoreCase(httpRequest.getMethod())) {
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
....
```

Comment: this is what I'd do, as its not tied to Jetty or anything else. Also, trivial to reason about.

Comment: If you decide to go this route ... be aware that a Filter won't be applied to non-context requests, and Filter behavior is subject to DispatcherType rules (which is very often overlooked).

Answer (score 2):

Jan's answer works (of course). However, it will cause jetty to print a warning on startup.

```
WARNING ... SecurityHandler ... has uncovered http methods for path ...
```

To avoid this first add the constraint as in Jan's answer (disable TRACE) and then add another constraint (allow everything but TRACE). I invoke the following code for each `ServletContextHandler`:

```
private void disableTraceMethodForHandler(final ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler) {
    SecurityHandler securityHandler = servletContextHandler.getSecurityHandler();
    if (securityHandler == null) {
        securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
        servletContextHandler.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);
    }
    if (securityHandler instanceof ConstraintSecurityHandler) {
        ConstraintSecurityHandler constraintSecurityHandler = (ConstraintSecurityHandler) securityHandler;

        ConstraintMapping disableTraceMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
        Constraint disableTraceConstraint = new Constraint();
        disableTraceConstraint.setName("Disable TRACE");
        disableTraceConstraint.setAuthenticate(true);
        disableTraceMapping.setConstraint(disableTraceConstraint);
        disableTraceMapping.setPathSpec("/");
        disableTraceMapping.setMethod("TRACE");
        constraintSecurityHandler.addConstraintMapping(disableTraceMapping);

        ConstraintMapping enableEverythingButTraceMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
        Constraint enableEverythingButTraceConstraint = new Constraint();
        enableEverythingButTraceConstraint.setName("Enable everything but TRACE");
        enableEverythingButTraceMapping.setConstraint(enableEverythingButTraceConstraint);
        enableEverythingButTraceMapping.setMethodOmissions(new String[] {"TRACE"});
        enableEverythingButTraceMapping.setPathSpec("/");
        constraintSecurityHandler.addConstraintMapping(enableEverythingButTraceMapping);
    }
}
```

I figured out this solution after I found [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-runtime/issues/34) in Google's appengine-java-vm-runtime and [the fix](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-runtime/pull/36/commits/82a43e86ef409499c33dc59eec427e6b467da69c), both by Jan. The code above should do the same as the XML config there.

Comment: This does work, however it throws a 403 (Forbidden) instead of the more appropriate 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Constraint, you can use an `HttpConfiguration.Customizer`.

Bonus is that this will apply to all request, even if they don't belong to a context, and works across all context specific web apps too.

```java
package jetty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpMethod;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;

public class RejectHttpMethodsDemo
{
    public static class BanHttpMethods implements HttpConfiguration.Customizer
    {
        private final EnumSet<HttpMethod> bannedMethods;

        public BanHttpMethods(EnumSet<HttpMethod> bannedMethods)
        {
            this.bannedMethods = bannedMethods;
        }

        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector, HttpConfiguration channelConfig, Request request)
        {
            HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.fromString(request.getMethod());
            if (bannedMethods.contains(httpMethod))
            {
                request.setHandled(true);
                request.getResponse().setStatus(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED_405);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();

        HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfig.addCustomizer(new BanHttpMethods(EnumSet.of(HttpMethod.TRACE, HttpMethod.MOVE)));
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
        connector.setPort(9090);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.addHandler(new AbstractHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
            {
                baseRequest.setHandled(true);
                response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.getWriter().printf("Hello, You asked to %s %s, that is all%n", baseRequest.getMethod(), baseRequest.getRequestURI());
            }
        });
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

            demoRequest(httpClient, server.getURI().resolve("/apple"), "GET");
            demoRequest(httpClient, server.getURI().resolve("/banana"), "TRACE");
            demoRequest(httpClient, server.getURI().resolve("/cherry"), "MOVE");
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            server.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void demoRequest(HttpClient httpClient, URI path, String method)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(path)
                .method(method, HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
            HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.printf("HTTP %s %s Response Status: %d%n", httpRequest.method(), httpRequest.uri(), httpResponse.statusCode());
            System.out.println(httpResponse.body());
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With output ...

```
2022-01-21 11:23:13.718:INFO::main: Logging initialized @210ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2022-01-21 11:23:13.775:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.43.v20210629; built: 2021-06-30T11:07:22.254Z; git: 526006ecfa3af7f1a27ef3a288e2bef7ea9dd7e8; jvm 11.0.12+7
2022-01-21 11:23:13.809:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@4fcd19b3{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9090}
2022-01-21 11:23:13.812:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @308ms
HTTP GET http://127.0.1.1:9090/apple Response Status: 200
Hello, You asked to GET /apple, that is all

HTTP TRACE http://127.0.1.1:9090/banana Response Status: 405

HTTP MOVE http://127.0.1.1:9090/cherry Response Status: 405

2022-01-21 11:23:14.186:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Stopped ServerConnector@4fcd19b3{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9090}
```